# Sequence diagrams using yii2 framework -vis.js libraries

Tags: javascript, php, html, yii2, vis.js

I want to use a SEQUENCE DIAGRAMS with arrows in it and some boxes over the arrows. these boxes are to print the data in them. How can i draw a diagram like that using YII2 mvc framework? How can i use vis.js for this?

i need to iterate several diagrams over a loop depends on the input data.

Edited:
This is my composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-basic",
    "description": "Yii 2 Basic Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "basic", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.14",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0",
        "2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget": "~1.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker": "dev-master",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datetimepicker": "dev-master",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2": "dev-master",
        "wadeshuler/yii2-sendgrid": "dev-master",
        "codeonyii/yii2-at-least-validator": "dev-master",
        "listfixer/yii2-remember-me": "*",
        "bower-asset/vis": "*",
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",

        "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
        "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1",
        "codeception/specify": "~0.4.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800,
        "fxp-asset": {
            "enabled": false
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "yii\\composer\\Installer::postInstall"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject",
            "yii\\composer\\Installer::postInstall"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject": {
            "setPermission": [
                {
                    "runtime": "0777",
                    "web/assets": "0777",
                    "yii": "0755"
                }
            ]
        },
        "yii\\composer\\Installer::postInstall": {
            "generateCookieValidationKey": [
                "config/web.php"
            ]
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is the location of my vis files in vendor.

C:\xampp\htdocs\ops_asst-2.1\vendor\bower-asset\vis

These are the files i have inside this

[image: These are the files i have in that folder.]

Answer (score 1):

I use the open source **vis.js** libraries.

https://visjs.org/

## Yii2-advanced Folder Structure

{app-root}

- frontend

  - assets

    - VisAsset.php
  - controllers

    - {foldername}Controller.php
  - views

    - {foldername}

      - workflow.js
      - view.php
- vendor

  - bower-asset

    - vis
    - {vis files}

## Add composer.json requirement:

Add the following to your composer.json:  `"bower-asset/vis": "*"`

Then run `composer update` to install the libray.

## Ensure Composer Config

Ensure your composer configuration has a place to install vis library under vendor/bower-assets.

```
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800,
        "fxp-asset": {
            "installer-paths": {
                "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
                "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
            }
        }
    },
```

## Create a AssetBundle

Create file in your app: `frontend/assets/VisAsset.php`

```
<?php

namespace frontend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * vis.js asset bundle.
 */
class VisAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    //public $basePath = '@webroot';
    //public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $sourcePath = '@bower';
    public $css = [
        'vis/dist/vis.css', 
    ];
    public $js = [
        'vis/dist/vis.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        //'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        //'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];   
}
```

## Create workflow.js Script

Create file: 'frontend/views/{folder-name}/workflow.js'

```
var nodesArray = [
  {id:  1, label: 'A-Label'},
  {id:  2, label: 'B-LAbel'},
];

var edgesArray = [
  {from: 1, to: 2},
];

var nodes = new vis.DataSet(nodesArray);
var edges = new vis.DataSet(edgesArray);

// create a network
var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
container.innerHTML = 'Loading';
var data = {
    nodes: nodes,
    edges: edges
};
var height = 400;
var width = 900;
var options = {
    autoResize: true,
    height: height +'px',
    width: width + 'px',
    layout: {
        hierarchical: {
            enabled:false,
            //levelSeparation: 150,
            //nodeSpacing: 200,
            //treeSpacing: 200,
            //blockShifting: true,
            //edgeMinimization: true,
            //parentCentralization: true,
            //direction: 'UD',        // UD, DU, LR, RL
            //sortMethod: 'directed'   // hubsize, directed
          }
    },
    nodes: {
        shape: 'box',
        margin: {
            top: 10,
            bottom: 10,
            left: 10,
            right: 10
        },
        font: {
            size: 18
        },
    },
    physics: false,
};
window.network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

## Update View

In your `frontend/views/{folder-name}/view.php` file add:

```
//Register the vis.js and vis.css vendor files.
app\assets\VisAsset::register($this); 
$this->registerJs($this->render('workflow.js'));
```

and

`<div id="mynetwork" style=""></div>`

[image: vis.js example]

Comment: Do i need to install or include anything else in the server for this to work ?

Comment: I did all these steps but still does not work. CSS border box getting displayed while js caused errors like vis not defined. then i put this, ```var vis = require('../../../ops_asst-2.1/vis/dist/vis.js');``` and then properties are not defined

Comment: Three things:
1. Are you using composer, and did you add the bower/vis to your composer and run composer update to install the dependency?
2. Could you posed your actual files and filenames, and your composer.json file. The namespaces will be important for instanced `app` would be your frontend or another name that you chose.
3. can you post the original error after you tried the above steps.

Comment: [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  Content-Length mismatch, received 32512 bytes out of the expected 3999824       (I receive this error while updating dependency.)

Comment: Let me see if that is vis.js specific or something going on with composer and packagist.org.

Comment: I edited the question with the necessary details of composer and the files i got as vis.js. dunno whether something is missing.

Comment: But it works right, you just get an error in the composer output log while it pulls the dependencies?

Comment: i get the error of vis not defined. "jQuery.Deferred exception: vis is not defined ReferenceError: vis is not defined"     this thing. I used composer update and got all installed. is there any way i can use the js within the view. without using a seperate workflow.js file?

Comment: I think your missing bower-asset install location in you composer config:
```    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800,
        "fxp-asset": {
            "installer-paths": {
                "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
                "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
            }
        }
    },```

Comment: I just added a compose.json section to address, let me know if that solves it.